# mysql records doesn't show in filemaker

Tags: filemaker

Very simple set up. one source table with 16 records located on MySQL database.

successful connection with external data, and add new table to relationships.
In layout view, only 6 or less records are shown. Never the full amount. see picture.
There is no sort, no find etc.

I tried to refresh window.
I have tried with a 16 records, 90 or 250 records for the source table in mysql.
Tried to close and re-open, sometime it goes to 3 records, sometimes 7, but never the full amount.
I have check with data viewer to see ALL records, only 6 are shown.
I have tried full clean reinstall, MySQL server, ODBC manager, FMP.
I have tried with a PostgreSQL database. Same issue.

It seems FMP or the connection does not want to upload the ALL records.

MacOS: 12.6.3
MySQL: 8.0.31
FMP: 19.6.3.302
ODBC manager: 1.0.22
ODBC FMP client installed

Is this a version of FMP problem? should i regress to older version?

Being trying for a couple of days. Really don't know what's the issue. Thanks for the help :)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sANvE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp5Zt.png)

Comment: Are you using Actual Technologies, Open Source Databases version 5.1.3?
MySQL's own ODBC drivers are not supported.
https://support.claris.com/s/article/Which-ODBC-data-sources-drivers-are-supported-with-External-SQL-Data-Sources-1503692938173?language=en_US

Comment: For MySQL ESS, Actual technologies ODBC drivers are required until version 5.7.21. But support article not showing anything for MySQL 8.
https://support.claris.com/s/article/Which-ODBC-data-sources-drivers-are-supported-with-External-SQL-Data-Sources-1503692938173?language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

yes i used the actual technology first. Not working. I have tried in combo with ESS although it is suppose to be for Postgres. Btw, the same issue with DB with postgres. sync issue.

I have found a working solution. using the iODBC administrator. NOT the actual technology. and create a connection with ANSI (NOT unicode). for me it works.

Thanks to: https://community.claris.com/en/s/question/0D53w00005tf8xCCAQ/when-trying-to-connect-to-an-odbc-source-i-get-all-working-except-the-last-step-this-action-cannot-be-performed-because-the-required-table-is-missing

I would like to understand why though. if someone can ever explain. or maybe actual tech is not 'up to date'?